# Dynamically generated metadata does not display grid

Tags: extjs, dynamic, extjs4

The following data is being used to load and display a grid dynamically. The only difference between the two grids is that the first reader takes in the data below *as is*, but the second grid only knows about the data and the `metaData` will be generated *on the fly*. I placed stubs for the fields and columns as this is not the issue and I haven't decided on how I will generate the data yet.

Both of the readers eventually pass the data below to the `JsonReader`'s `readRecords()`' function via `this.callParent([data]);`, but the second one does not display the data. The data is there, but I am not sure why it does not display?

[image]

There are two links to demos below. The first is a JSFiddle that loads from memory and the second is a Sencha Fiddle that loads through AJAX.

### Snippet

```js
var rawFields = [
    { "name": "year",     "type": "int" },
    { "name": "standard", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "bitRate",  "type": "float" }
];

var rawColumns = [
    { "text" : "Year",     "dataIndex" : "year",     "flex" : 1 },
    { "text" : "Standard", "dataIndex" : "standard", "flex" : 1 },
    { "text" : "Bit/Sec",  "dataIndex" : "bitRate",  "flex" : 1 }
];
```

```js
Ext.define('Example.reader.DynamicReader', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
    alias : 'reader.dynamicReader',

    readRecords : function(data) {
        var response = {
            data: data,
            metaData : this.createMetaData(data),
            success: true
        };
        console.log(response);
        return this.callParent([response]);
    },

    createMetaData : function(data) {
        return {
            idProperty : "id",
            fields : rawFields,  // These will eventually be generated...
            columns : rawColumns // These will eventually be generated...
        };
    }
});
```

### Data

```js
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "year": 1997,
            "standard": "802.11",
            "bitRate": 2000000
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "year": 1999,
            "standard": "802.11b",
            "bitRate": 11000000
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "year": 1999,
            "standard": "802.11a",
            "bitRate": 54000000
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "year": 2003,
            "standard": "802.11g",
            "bitRate": 54000000
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "year": 2007,
            "standard": "802.11n",
            "bitRate": 600000000
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "year": 2012,
            "standard": "802.11ac",
            "bitRate": 1000000000
        }
    ],
    "metaData": {
        "idProperty": "id",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "year",
                "type": "int"
            },
            {
                "name": "standard",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "bitRate",
                "type": "float"
            }
        ],
        "columns": [
            {
                "text": "Year",
                "dataIndex": "year",
                "flex": 1
            },
            {
                "text": "Standard",
                "dataIndex": "standard",
                "flex": 1
            },
            {
                "text": "Bit/Sec",
                "dataIndex": "bitRate",
                "flex": 1
            }
        ],
        "success": true
    }
}
```

### Demos

The following examples both achieve the same thing, so the only difference is the loading of the data.

#### Loading from Memory

http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/zy4z5z8a/

#### Loading from AJAX

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/d3l

Comment: after lot of reading i felt Kendo UI is much better than ExtJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer. I needed to specify a root value for the reader so that the data can be mapped properly.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.widget("dynamicGrid", {
        title: 'WiFi LAN Data Rates [Dynamic]',
        renderTo: Ext.get('example-grid-dynamic'),
        readerType: 'dynamicReader',
        // This need to match the 'data' key specified in the `response` object
        // that was created in readRecords().
        readerRoot: 'data',
        data : rawData
    });
});
```

The documentation for `root` notes that the `root` property has to map to the data portion of the response.

Documentation for `Json.root`:

> ### `Ext.data.reader.Json.root`
>
> #### `root` : `String`
>
> The name of the property which contains the data items corresponding to the Model(s) for which this Reader is configured. For JSON reader it's a property name (or a dot-separated list of property names if the root is nested). For XML reader it's a CSS selector. For Array reader the root is not applicable since the data is assumed to be a single-level array of arrays.